# Showing $x$ and $y$ are permutations of one another for Cauchy joint distribution

Tags: probability, polynomials

This is similar to a question I [just asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963078/proof-check-showing-x-and-y-must-be-permutations-of-one-another-given) but the method there does not work here.

Consider the joint distribution of iid Cauchy random variables

$$f(x|\theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2}$$

My goal is to show that if

$$\prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+x_i^2}{1+(x_i-\theta)^2} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{1+y_i^2}{1+(y_i-\theta)^2}$$

for at least $2n+1$ values of $\theta$, then the vectors $x,y$ are permutations of one another.

I have successfully shown that the above implies

$$\prod_{i=1}^n (1+(x_i-\theta)^2) = \prod_{i=1}^n (1+(y_i-\theta)^2)$$

for all values of $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$.

But here I am stuck. Essentially, I guess, I need to show that this factorisation is unique (up to permutations), but since this is not in the form $\prod_i (\eta_i-\theta)$ I cannot use the uniqueness of roots to complete this.

I am wondering if there is a theorem for polynomial factorisations that can help me finish this last step?

I know it's true as this is a well known result of the Cauchy distribution (despite the fact the proof is surprisingly hard to find...)

### Edit

I just realised the above factorisation implies each polynomial has $2n$ complex roots of the form

$$x_i  \pm i$$

$$y_i \pm i$$

I am unfamilar with complex roots, but I think this implies $x$ is a permutation has $y$, as a polynomial of degree $2n$ can have at most $2n$ roots, complex or real. Is this correct?