# Can we conclude that if $|x|-|y|=|x-a|-|y-a|$ then $x=y$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I want to prove a secondary result by induction, but to complete it relies on the fact that

$$|x|-|y|=|x-a|-|y-a| \implies x = y$$

It seems intuitively true to me, since the $-a$ excludes the case $x=-y$ and vise versa. But at the same time I would be surprised if some kind of special case construction could violate this.

Is this result true? And if so, is there an easy  way I can show this?

### edit:

Forgot to add important details:

1. $a \neq 0$ by construction
2. We can extend this to hold for any $a_1,\dots,a_n$ so long as $n$ is finite.

Comment: Counterexample: $a=0,x=1,y=-1$.

Comment: @bof does the fact we can make this hold for any $ a \in \mathbb{R}$ make it true then? or specifically, if we exclude a = 0? Thanks for the simple counter example by the way

Comment: Maybe you are missing a quantifier? Maybe you meant to ask, "if $|x|-|y|=|x-a|-|y-a|$ for all $a$, can we conclude that $x=y$?

Comment: Hmm I can't say for all $a$. But I can say for all $a_1, \dots, a_n$ where $a_i \neq 0$ and $n$ is any finite number.

Comment: Basically Ive constructed a sub family of distributions indexed by $a_1,\dots,a_n$ and want to show a property for these $a_i$ which will then imply the same result for the original family of distributions. I am free to choose any $a_i$ so long as $n$ is finite. And if I choose those $a_i$, then the property stated immediately holds for all $a_i$. hope that makes sense

Comment: Typo: I meant $x=10$, $y=9$, $a=3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are in general 16 cases that may be reduced with the specified $a_1$ and $a_2$.

$$|x - a_1| - |y - a_1| = |x - a_2| - | y - a_2| $$

Here for the right hand side $a_2 = a$ (that can be either positive or negative) is the critical point where we need to split $x$-versus-$a$ and $y$-versus-$a$ so that's $4$ from 2-by-2.

For the left hand side $a_1 = 0$ is a critical point, with also $4$ combo of $x$-versus-$0$ times $y$-versus-$0$.

Given $a_1 = 0$, if you want to exclude $a_2 = a = 0$, that will have no effect (at most this can effect two cases).

### Case++++

If $x>0,y>0,x>a,y>a$, then
$$x - y = (x-a)-(y-a) \implies \text{trivial identity, we learn nothing}$$
Numerical example, $x = 2,y=1, a = -\pi \implies 1 = (2-\pi)-(1-\pi)$

### Case+++-

If $x>0,y>0,x>a,y\color{magenta}<a$, thus necessarily $a$ is positive as well since $a > y >0$
$$x - y = (x-a)-(a-y) \implies -y = -2a + y \implies y = a$$
Numerical example, $x = 4, a = \pi \implies 4-y = (4-\pi)-(\pi-y)$

### Case-+++

If $x \color{magenta}\leq 0,y>0,x>a,y>a$, where the last condition is sort of redundant since $y > 0 \leq x > a$ by the previous three.
$$-x - y = (x-a)-(y-a) \implies -x-y = x - y \implies x = 0$$
Numerical example $y = 1, a = -\pi \implies -x-1 = (x-\pi)-(1-\pi)$

### Shall I go on?

nah, you get the point

Comment: Thats a great way of explaining it, thanks. That said, I know that if $\frac{\sum_i |x_i - \theta|}{\sum_i |y_i - \theta|}$ does not depend on $\theta$, then $x$ and $y$ must be permutations of one another (as order statistics are minimal sufficient for double exponential distribution). Can you see a way I can show this (a short hint would be very helpful).

Comment: I saw you [other post about the permutation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2963160) so I know your end goal. Honestly I'm not familiar with any satisfying proof of that "well-known" fact either. Most likely, splitting into $(2^n)^2$ cases or with reduction due to $a_1 = 0$ like demonstrated here for $n = 2$ is definitely not the way to go. Sorry can't help here as of this moment.

Comment: No worries. I really appreciate your post, it made this line of thinking a lot clearer for me!